# Real time chart/graph with c# from OPC server

Tags: c#, graph, charts, opc

I want to create an application with c# in order to plot values in real time chart/graph from OPC Server with a client c#.
So, the communication is between a Sentron PAC 3200 ( Modbus protocol) and the c # client using KEPServer.
Please i need help : source codes, ideas, any thing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should be writing your own code by reading the Modbus protocol specifications.

Comment: A quick first search gives me this: http://www.dataloggersuite.com/tutorials/modbus-tcp-sentron-pac3200.htm - This might be your starting point..

Comment: I didn't mean that my code is with Modbus protocol specifications, i already developed a c# client an i can read the values of the sentron pac 3200 from the opc server itself.

Comment: So now i just need how to plot those values in a real time chart/graph

Comment: Edit your question then. There are many options available for drawing.. search on internet or this site before asking. And pls then be specific to a product or code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/).  I haven't used it but it looks like a nice quick solution.  They support WPF, UWP, and WinForms.